# Excel: Making the function pick up text form another cell and testing (with COUNF.IF) if some other cell has the text and something else

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Lets say I have an excel sheet.
Cell A1 has the text "car". I need to count all the cells with the word "car" as a part of centence with COUNT.IF. For example if another cell has the pharace "Car is driving fast" the COUNT.IF can pick it up based on the value in A1. Now my COUNT.IF -function has the "* car *" manually written. If I change the value in A1 I have to manually change the code. Is there a way or another function that would do the tric?

See above. My current function is written like this

=IF(COUNT.IF($C$20:$Q$21;"* car *") * 1=0;"";COUNT.IF($C$20:$Q$21;" * ("*car *")*1)

But id like to pick the word car from another cell and I cant copy the function efficiently since I have to manually fill the words I want to search from phraces. I just need the amount of cell with a word given by A1 as part of a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something along these lines:

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&A1&" "," "&C20:Q21&" ")))
```

Swap `SUM()` with `SUMPRODUCT()` if you are using excel prior to ms365/2021

Do note that the wap you have set this up is it not checking for the word 'car' with leading/trailing punctuation marks.